# SQL SELECT & multiple AND query statement in visual c#

Tags: c#, sql, select

In this query statement i want sum of the number of days in the `'datetime'` column where `emp_ID` equals to selected `emp_ID` in the `textBox2` 'and' `leavetype = Fullday` 'and' `status = approved`. this is my code

```
string selectSql = 
"Select sum(datetime) 
 From Lea_information 
 Where emp_ID= ('" + textBox2.Text + "') 
 and (leave_type,status) = values (Fullday,Approved)";
```

Comment: Did you want any help from us or were you just saying? I'm sure you would have told us if you were having some kind of problem...

Comment: yes i want help, sorry for my bad English. above statement is not working.

Comment: also do you want to get the sum of the days or the count?

Comment: @user3125185: It wasn't the bad english that was the problem (its good enough to not have even occurred to me). Its the fact that you didn't describe what your problem was, what error message you got, etc. A good question (or bug report) should always contain the exact error you are getting since error messages are there to help debugging.

Comment: @PeterRing - i wanted the sum not the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
string selectSql = 
"Select sum(datetime) 
 From Lea_information 
 Where emp_ID= '" + textBox2.Text + "'
 AND leave_type ='Fullday' 
 AND status = 'Approved'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ing selectSql = "Select sum(datetime) from Lea_information where emp_ID= ('" + textBox2.Text + "') and leave_type = FullDay and status = Approved)";
```

Not sure which database you are using, but I've never seen statements like you have written there before.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, its working perfectly! im sorry to tell you that im still a beginner.